# htaccess 301 redirect urls with question mark

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I noticed that there are many links reported in Google Search Console that have a question mark after at the root of the domain `(index.php.)`

This happened because I had redirected an old domain to my new one.
I want to use htaccess to 301 ONLY pages that have a question mark at the root level.

For example:

```
?name=TheFoolOnTheHill
?name=PennyLane
```

would both redirect to the root level of the domain.

But it would NOT effect other urls such as:

```
/songs/?name=TheFoolOnTheHill
/songs/?name=PennyLane
```

I would appreciate any help on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Rewrite for this. Give this a try for any url with a query string at the root level.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]
```

URL like this

```
http://example.com/?name=123
```

Will redirect to root.

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edit. That was needed to prevent redirect loop

Comment: @anubhava yes, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to solve with your .htaccess file.

```
Redirect 301 ?name=TheFoolOnTheHill /
Redirect 301 ?name=PennyLane /
```

Comment: Yes.  I was hoping I could get the formula for redirecting anything at the root level with a ? to the root.  But it would ignore it if it occurred in other directories.

Comment: In this case you are setting each of your track error URL in google to your root. Ok, sometimes it could be a very large number, but once you made this you will no more to get these errors.